# Photoshop alter colors in blue white

Tags: colors, photoshop, alter

I'm trying to make an header in Photoshop but I want the image I use to only have two base colors.

Just like:

[image]

How do I make this happen? And is it possible to just adjust one layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basics is use hue/saturation in Image>Adjustment>hue/saturation tick the colorise in the bottom and enjoy colouring